# chainsaw 2.1 doesn't load my receiver from a conf file

Tags: apache-chainsaw

After using chainsaw 2.1 for months now, my conf is not loaded anymore.

i tried to delete the folder .chainsaw and restart from fresh install and nothing happens.

the receiver doesn't show at all.

Can anyone guide me to a tip to solve this situation.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Does the UI appear?  If so, check the logging in the chainsaw-log tab.

The shell you launch Chainsaw in should show some configuration information.